# How to remove getbutton.io branding

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- GetButton.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            whatsapp: "+123456789", // WhatsApp number
            telegram: "username", // Telegram bot username
            call_to_action: "Need Help ?", // Call to action
            button_color: "#A8CE50", // Color of button
            position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "whatsapp,telegram", // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "getbutton.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /GetButton.io widget -->
```

If we use this free getbuttton.io widget then it shows getbutton.io branding so, is there any way to remove that branding using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will take like 2 seconds to load. so you can do something like this.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hasyTc");
    x[0].remove();
},2000)
```

you can increase 2sec to 5 if it takes more time to load.

Comment: Well, it's working but not all the time. If someone refreshes the page after coming to the website ( it appears again )

Comment: @Mr3ko because the elements gets renders again. if there is a event that fires after getButton.io rendered fully you can use this implementation without the setTimeout which will be more effective. Or you can increase timeout duration to 5000 (5sec) to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
I removed GetButton by css code ..

.eARkMz {

    opacity: 1;
    display: none !important;
    margin-top: 7px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 64px;
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    border: 0px;
    max-width: inherit;
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175) !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).